# Can wifi shield connect to local network without internet?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I have an Arduino Uno and a Texas Instruments CC3000 WiFi shield. I need to connect the Arduino to a local network which has no Internet access so that it can send information to a computer also connected to the same local network. I am using a Linksys WRT120N for the local network.

I can't use the Internet access WiFi because it is WPA2 Enterprise which is why I created the local network. Currently the computer is connected to the local network via WiFi.

I have downloaded and installed the correct library but when I run the connection test, it searches for Internet access which doesn't exist and sends back errors.

How do I verify that it is connecting to the local network?

Btw, I have almost no experience coding an Arduino but I have access to people who are proficient; However, they have no experience with a WiFi shield.

Comment: Why not modify the connection test to look for a local system instead?

Comment: Hi Nick, If my answer below doesn't help, please provide the EXACT error message/output, a link to the library, and a copy of your code.

Comment: So, I took the arduino home to attempt to connect to my own WPA2 network and for some reason, the serial monitor keeps showing it attempting to connect with the old network name. I have reloaded the code and changed the SSID and password within the code. Here is a link to the library I downloaded. The library zip file download link is at the bottom of the page under documents.  https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12071  Also, I am using the code provided by the library called connection test. The only things I changed within the code are the SSID name and the password.

Comment: I don't know how to share my code with all of you because it is too long to place in here. The code is available in the library zip file.

Comment: Hi Nick. I reviewed the ConnectionTest.ino file and it should be providing some good diagnostic information through the serial port. Have your colleagues show you how to use the Serial monitor. I'd be happy to review the Serial Monitor output if you post it here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your own local network, you may need a DHCP server to give it an IP address, or you will have to configure your Arduino with a static ip. I can't think of a reason why it would need internet access, but it is not uncommon for devices to refer (incorrectly) to connectivity issues on the local network as "internet" issues.